# Edge launches but fails to navigate to uri

Tags: c#, windows-10, microsoft-edge, selenium-remotedriver

I am using selenium remotedriver(with C#) for chrome and edge. The tests seem to run fine on the chrome browser but not on edge. Edge is launched but fails to navigate to the specified uri.

I tried to make sure, I have the same version of webdriver as the installed version of edge, I am on windows 10 so it is already turned on.

```
var options = new EdgeOptions();
options.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Eager;

_driver = new EdgeDriver(driverPath,options);
_driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");
```

[The image contains the nuget packages added to the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZldc.png)
Microsoft Edge 44.18362.329.0 that is installed. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to test the issue on my side with Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0, Windows 10, Selenium web driver version V3.141.0

Tested code:

```
class Program
    {
        private static StringBuilder verificationErrors;

        [Obsolete]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            var options = new EdgeOptions();
            options.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Eager;

            IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");
        }
    }
```

Code is working fine on my side and opening the web page without any issue.

Output:

[image]

I can see various entries for Web drivers in your package manager.

I suggest you to just installed the Selenium web driver v3.141.0 in new separate project and try to run this code in it to check whether it helps solve the issue or not.

If it solves the issue than remove unnecessary entries from your project may help to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Deepak, tried in a new program and was able to navigate to google. I removed the extra libraries(cleaned and rebuilt) in my original project that I was working on initially :( Edge was still failing to launch then I had to copy MicrosoftWebDriver.exe present on windows 10 and copied it to the bin folder of the project. All set!